# Spaces in the "Word" began to be replaced by dots. How to get rid of them?

Tags: microsoft-word

Somehow the spaces in my "Word" document started being replaced by dots:

[image: dots in words]

How can I switch it back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you've turned on "show formatting".

Ctrl+* (control-shift-8) should hide the formatting marks.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/show-or-hide-formatting-marks-HP005189641.aspx

Comment: The keyboard combination for toggling “Show formatting” is basically Ctrl Shift 8. Depending on the keyboard, this could also be described as Ctrl * or something else; on my keyboard for example, it’s Ctrl (. You can alternatively click on the “¶” symbol in the user interface (its placement varies by Word version).